# Automattically set Id when Setting Foreign Class property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using EntityFramework and I have to classes simplified as below:

```
public class Class1
{
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public int Class2_Id { get; set; }
  [ForeignKey("Class2_Id")]
  public virtual Class2 Class2 { get; set; }
}

public class Class2
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Can I, before calling `db.SaveChanges()`, automatically set `Class1.Class2.Id` when setting `Class1.Class2` property? I want to achieve this without the need put this logic at the setter of `Class1.Class2` property.

Comment: *I want to achieve this without the need put this logic at the setter o Class1.Class2 property* In other words, you want EF to do that for you. But you already know it's not doing it, so what's the question?

Comment: If there is any way to do the set. Since the Class2 property has an attribute that map the Class2_Id property, it would be possible to programmatically set the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a partial class extend from DbContext and override the SaveChanges

```
public partial class YourEntities : DbContext
{
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var Class1 = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(
            e => e.State == EntityState.Added &&
                 e.Entity is Class1);
        // Class1.Class2.Id // your logic ...

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: It can work for this specifc class Class1. I was looking for a generic way to solve that. Maybe it can be done evolving this idea... I'll try

Comment: @mqueirozcorreia No you can remove `&& e.Entity is Class1` and it will be for everything, If you want that